# Django query to retrieve items that are selected as foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, imagine there is a model `City` which has a foreign key `Country`. In the database, some Countries were selected in one or more cities, and some in none.

How can we find only those countries that are selected in one or more cities, excluding those that aren't selected at all?

Comment: I had this as an answer but I'm not 100% it will work and I can't test it at the moment. Try: `Country.objects.exclude(city__isnull=True)`. [You have access to the reverse relationship when querying](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) so you should just be able to exclude those that don't have a backward relationship to the city. If it works I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Unfortunately `Country` doesn't have the field `City`, it's the other way around. Although `Country` does have the `city_set` property; I need only those Countries where this set is not empty.

Comment: You should be able to follow the relationship backwards within the query. Countries which have +1 cities should be `(city__isnull=False)` then.

Comment: @BerislavLopac, pastylegs answer should work in your situation. If City has an FK to Country, django will generate the join automatically if you query it as a field. @pastylegs why did you delete your answer? `Country.objects.filter(city__isnull=False) # Countries with cities pointing to it`.

Comment: I wasn't able to test it so wasn't sure it was right ;) I'll undelete it now

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get all countries that have at least one city
Country.objects.exclude(city__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Country.objects.annotate(city_count=Count('city_set')).filter(city_count__gt=1)
```

Docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates